# How to log textbox text into IIS Advanced Logging when user clicks submit button

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-advanced-logging

I would like to use IIS 7.5+ Advanced logging to log a textbox control value (text) from a IIS web page when a user clicks the submit button on that page in addition to the regular items it already logs.  The URL does not change when user clicks the submit button.  Is there a way to configure this without custom coding and re-compiling the application?

Inside the Failed Request Tracing Logs I see the text from the textbox control that I would like to capture under: GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY and GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY BUFFER.

If there is no way to do this I will look to find code (VB code) that logs the textbox value to the IIS log file.  Does anyone have samples of posting to a custom IIS log field in VB?

Comment: I'm giving up on the configuration-only option.  Does anyone have a good link/resource showing how to add a custom  field (text) to the IIS 7 Advanced log AND how to write that custom value (text) to the IIS log?  I can't find that VB.NET sample code anymore...